# Remember CheckedListBox items state using a text file

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010, checkedlistbox

I'm writing code to mark the checkboxes of a `CheckedListBox` of when the strings in my text file match the items in my `CheckedListBox`.

```
Dim fl As String = s.ToString() + "\Script\" + "DB_NAME.txt"

If File.Exists(fl) Then
    If File.Exists(fl) Then
        Dim line As String
        Dim i As Integer

        Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(s.ToString() + "\Script\" + "DB_NAME.txt")

            Do Until reader.Peek = -1
                line = reader.ReadLine

                'For Each Item As DataRowView In grd_tabledata.Items
                '    Dim text As String = Item(0).ToString()
                '    If (text = line) Then
                '        grd_tabledata.SetItemChecked(text, True)
                '    End If
                '    MsgBox(text)
                'Next

                Do While (i <= grd_tabledata.Items.Count)
                    If (CType(grd_tabledata.Items(i), String) = line) Then
                        grd_tabledata.SetItemChecked(i, True)
                    End If

                    'i = (i + 1)
                Loop
            Loop

        End Using

    End
End
```

But I get an error like:

> 'Conversion from type 'DataRowView' to type 'String' is not valid.'

I would like to mark the `CheckedListBox` items when a corresponding entry exists in that file.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Mark the corresponding checkboxlist item when the entry exists in the file?

Comment: i am saving some field of checkbox list in text file and want to read this text file and check checkbox list items as per text file string.my checkbox list is already bind from database.

Comment: Mark the corresponding checkbox list item when the entry exists in the file yes i want to achieve this.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that grd_tabledata is the name of your CheckedListBox control and not the DataSource for the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to remeber the state of the **CheckedListBox** using a text file.

I created a dummy solution with a windows Form (`Form1`) containing a CheckedListBox (`CheckedListBox1`), and a Button (`Button1`) which updates the items in the CheckedListBox according to the content in the `"DB_NAME.txt"` text file.

[image]

**Form1**

[image]

**Form1.vb**

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpdateButton.Click

        Dim filename As String = "DB_NAME.txt"

        'Dim filename As String = s.ToString() + "\Script\" + "DB_NAME.txt"

        If Not File.Exists(filename) Then Return

        Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(filename)
            Do Until reader.Peek = -1
                Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine

                For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
                    If (CheckedListBox1.Items(i).ToString = line) Then CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, True)
                Next
            Loop
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

The content of the text file `"DB_NAME.txt"` is:

```
item C
item D
```

And finally, at run time, after clicking on the 'Update' button, you get:

[image]

If you are still in trouble, I recommend isolating your issue in a dummy solution and debugging using breakpoints to understand what are exactly the variable types you are working with.

I believe you are still getting exceptions because you are calling methods and properties which do not exist in your object. That's probably because you assume this object is of a given type, when it is not.

Comment: i got error like 'Class 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox' cannot be indexed because it has no default property.' and grd_tabledata is my checkboxlist name.

Comment: can you please provide code in detail.?because i can't understand what to do.

Comment: @NimishaPrajapati: I updated my answer to reflect your input.

Comment: not working. got 'system.data.datarowview' in grd_tabledata.Items(i).ToString so checkedlistbox item is not chekced

Comment: @NimishaPrajapati: would you please add to your question that code where you declare the grd_tabledata variable? I believe you mistankenly think it is of type CheckedListBox, but it is not. Probably your CheckedListBox has another name, like e.g. CheckedListBox1.

Comment: @NimishaPrajapati: I created a sample project with the code above declaring grd_tabledata as a CheckedListBox and tested the code above (it runs smoothly). Could you try to isolate your problem in a very simple dummy solution, then update the code of your question? Maybe you will easily find the cause of the error with this approach. Also, try debugging and set breakpoints in your code to analyse what is the runtime type of grd_tabledata (it is probably not of type CheckedListBox).

Answer (score 0):

Within your code just replace your Do until loop with following code

```
For i=0 To grd_tabledata.Items.count -1
    If (CType(grd_tabledata.Items(i), String) = line) Then
           grd_tabledata.SetItemChecked(i, True)
             Exit For
         End If 
 Next
```